How to know what a tag should mean: branching-strategy
For this specific case branching-strategy the tag-wiki is (currently) empty and there was a request to update this tag, to mean version-control branching strategy.
That makes sense to me and many use the tag that way, but some questions with the tag are about branching strategy in optimizations (scip pyomo), and other branching things.
How to decide?

Eh, if there is already mixed usage, it probably needs to be disambiguated. Because otherwise you "decide" what it means based on the usage. Unless you're absolutely certain there is only one meaning for a tag and don't need to examine the usage. Which is very rarely the case.

So, in practice adding a description to any tag lacking a description requires a disambiguating process first?

@HansOlsson no only where it is necessary, like where adding the tag description would  cause questions to have the wrong tag linked to them, as you have already identified. You have identified that there are not one but two problems that need solving in order for this situation to become measurably better instead of just changing the way in which it is suboptimal.

@HansOlsson I didn't say that. I said that often that would be the case. Because a tag with no usage guidance in the wild is very often used in different contexts. This is exactly what you found right now. But some tags are not ambiguous or are not used in ambiguous manner. Often I find a tag with no description and maybe 5 questions that use it. I look at them and figure out it's one single product, so I just edit in the tag information to describe how it's currently used. No disambiguation needed. As with most things - there is no silver bullet to apply for every single tag.

Comparing the Newest and Activity sort, looks like it was first created in 2010 on this question about version control branching strategy, so at least that was the intended usage.
